# Can I install modules to my wildfly through cli in domain mode?

Tags: configuration, wildfly, config

First question is supported, to manage add module from one point to all host?

If I run my wildfly domain mode I can't run this

```
[domain@127.0.0.1:9999 /] module add --name=com.oracle.jdbc --resources=/path/to/ojdbc6.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api
```

answer:

```
The command is not available in the current context (e.g. required subsystems or connection to the controller might be unavailable).
```

Answer (score 3):

The module operation doesn't work in domain mode because it copies the files locally.
One solution also is to use galleon to provision your modules

Comment: Can I have some example, how can I add a module to an existing wildfly? Thank you, the answer.

Comment: https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-datasources-galleon-pack  But it isn't very well documented. I think with ansible and cli is today the best solution.

Comment: https://wildfly.org/news/2019/12/17/Ship-your-WildFly-additions-via-Galleon-feature-packs/https://wildfly.org/news/2019/12/17/Ship-your-WildFly-additions-via-Galleon-feature-packs/ https://docs.wildfly.org/galleon/ may help

Answer (score 0):

I found a very good blog:

https://in.relation.to/2017/05/29/creating-patches-for-wildfly/

This works. If you will add a module to modules/com/.. then in the projekt you have to put modules/system/layers/base/com/..

So you can manage the differences of wildfly-s.